# HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized from Local IIS

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have created site on my local machine that works fine on debug mode but when i put the site on local iis (7.5) of my machine i get

HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Authentication Settings
I have windows impersonation and windows authentication enabled and everything else in that section is disabled

All the folder have full permissions

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Maybe your Windows event log will provide some more insight. It usually contains some extra information for these kinds of errors.

Comment: you can also turn on web site logging and look in the IIS web logs, not sure if they would provide more info or not.

Answer (score 31):

As a quick and dirty fix, grant the `IIS_IUSRS` group *Read/Execute* or *Modify* permissions to your web folder... **BUT DON'T DO THIS ON AN INTERNET FACING SERVER**, read on....

To fix this properly you should grant the Application Pool Identity for your site *Read/Execute* or *Modify* permissions to your application's web folder. To do this:

1. Open IIS Manager, navigate to your website or application folder where the site is deployed to.
2. Open Advanced Settings (it's on the right hand *Actions* pane).
3. Note down the *Application Pool* name then close this window
4. Double click on the *Authentication* icon to open the authentication settings
5. Disable *Windows Authentication*
6. Right click on *Anonymous Authentication* and click `Edit`
7. Choose the `Application pool identity` radio button the click `OK`
8. Select the Application Pools node from IIS manager tree on left and select the Application Pool name you noted down in step 3
9. Right click and select *Advanced Settings*
10. Expand the Process Model settings and choose `ApplicationPoolIdentity` from the *"Built-in account"* drop down list then click `OK`.
11. Click `OK` again to save and dismiss the Application Pool advanced settings page
12. Open an Administrator command line (right click on the CMD icon and select "Run As Administrator". It'll be somewhere on your start menu, probably under Accessories.
13. Run the following command:

`icacls <path_to_site> /grant "IIS APPPOOL\<app_pool_name>"(CI)(OI)(M)`

For example:

`icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\ /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DEFAULTAPPPOOL":(CI)(OI)(M)`

If all is good `icacls.exe` will report:

```
processed file: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I get this blooming annoying problem every time I do a fresh install.  I'll be Googling for this error again in about 3 years! ;-)

Comment: Just as a note, I had to take the additional steps outlined in this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861.  It's a problem that occurs when you use custom headers to browse a website on a local loopback address.

Comment: This got me a bit closer. Should be marked as the answer

Comment: As a suggestion, it is better to run the app-pool under a service account (so that the password does not expire). For isolation, we generally have one service account per application.
The service account should be given the following permissions on the web root folder: Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read & Write.

Comment: @KevinSwann - the `IIS APPPOOL\<pool_name>` doo hickey is a service account, and one that's automatically generated on the fly so you don't need to worry about configuring passwords and setting privileges (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff641731(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @KevinSwann see also: https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities - this is how it's done correctly. Trust me I work for a shared hoster, this is how it's done.

Comment: OMG,  I am nearly positive that doing this has jacked up my ability to use Trusted Connection to various SQL Server instances !  Ughhh!!!

Answer (score 10):

In my case this had nothing to do with permissions. This is the "loopback check" protection. The problem was because I was connecting from the local machine that had the IIS.

Symptoms are: You connect and you get a browser prompt to insert credentials 3 times, then an HTTP 401.1 error.

Testing from a different computer works well.

Some sites will tell you to disable the "loopback check", but instead you have to add the FQDN domain you're connecting to to a whitelist, as described in this serverfault response:

https://serverfault.com/a/485011/415362

Comment: This is enormously helpful, I've been pulling my hair out today over this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd add that it's extremely likely to be this if you've added a binding to the site that uses a hostname you've specified in your hosts file (to 127.0.0.1).

Comment: you are the best, i have 1 server that needed this, and i have another server that did not need. I HAVE NO IDEA why one works and one does not.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same issue. i simply remove the application. created a new floder and hosted it again. problem solved.

Comment: Could you describe the steps you took? I don't understand why this would work - it's more likely something to do with permissions on the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late in coming, but an alternative that I sometimes forget is time difference.  In a domain environment, run "Net Time /SET" to synchronise with the AD Box.

Additional Reading:

For all of this to work and to ensure security, the domain controllers and clients must have the same time. Windows operating systems include the Time Service tool (W32Time service). Kerberos authentication will work if the time interval between the relevant computers is within the maximum enabled time parameters. The default is five minutes. You can also turn off the Time Service tool and install a third-party time service. Of course, if you have problems authenticating, you should make sure that the time is correct for the domain controllers and the client that is experiencing the problem.
(Source:  https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/server-authentication.html)

Heavier Reading:

.... In addition, IT professionals should understand how Windows Time Service works because Kerberos security is highly dependent on time services. ....
(Source: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2012/02/01/understanding-the-essentials-of-the-kerberos-protocol.aspx )