# iis7 website set up

Tags: iis, iis-7

I've done this a few times in IIS 6 but never on IIS 7 so I'm having a bit of trouble...

To create a website on IIS 7, do I create a website or an application?

Also, what goes on the bindings (host name, ip address)?

I want www.whatever.com to point to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\whatever

so far I got www.whatever.com to point to C:\inetpub\wwwroot, but I can't figure out how to make it point to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\whatever.

EDIT:
ok, I managed to point the site to the right folder. now I get this error:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Thanks

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference but the server is on Amazon EC2

Comment: I answered a question some time ago that might help you out: > [HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized from Local IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892547/http-error-401-1-unauthorized-from-local-iis/3892915#3892915)

Comment: doesn't this question belong to serverfault?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to allow the ASPNET internet guest account (or whatever anonymous access account you use) access to the folder. Edit the security permissions and make sure to replace all children permissions.

Comment: hmm not sure I follow you. How do I set that up?

Comment: Take a look at this article. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244(WS.10).aspx
First setup the IUSR account access the website in IIS, then make sure that account has read (and write if needed) to the website directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Wanted to run website on my local machine.
I made sure Anonymous authentication is enabled. Also, I set Anonymous Authentication credentials to "Application pool identity". It solved my problem.