# There is no Anonymous Authentication on fresh install IIS 10 (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I just did a fresh install of IIS 10 on a Windows Server 2019 (Datacenter Edition). Then, did a simple `localhost` request to confirm that all was done successfully. I end up receiving a 401 response.

Checking further in IIS Manager, I found out that there is no `Anonymous Authentication` present.

[image: IIS Manager with no Anonymous Authentication]

As you can see, it's not a matter of Enabling/Configuring it as answered here: [HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized from Local IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892547/http-error-401-1-unauthorized-from-local-iis)

It's a matter that **there is NO `Anonymous Authentication`** even to configure or enable.

And here is a picture of another webserver, with exactly same environment, which I did the exact same process of installation, where `Anonymous Authentication` is present as expected.

[image: IIS Manager with Anonymous Authentication, correctly present]

So, how can I "install" `Anonymous Authentication` on IIS 10, when it is not installed/present by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after trying everything I could, I was unable to solve it. End up removing IIS completely, and installed it again.

**Immediately after (re)installation the problem was solved**, and everything was exactly as it should be. `Anonymous Authentication` show up on Authentication Pane, and requests were responded successfully.

So, I guess i experienced a corrupted IIS10 installation, even I do not recall seeing any warning about it.

Note 1: Environment was Azure VM, Windows 2019 Datacenter Edition, IIS10.
Note 2: During first installation, the machine (VM) had only 1GB of memory. I don't know if this could lead to the corrupted installation.
Note 3: To uninstall IIS 10 on Windows 2019, it's simple like: open "Server Manager" -> click on "Manage" -> click on "Remove Roles and Features" -> uncheck "Web Server (IIS)" -> then simply follow the wizard...

[image: Remove IIS 10 on Windows 2019 - Remove Roles and Features on Server Manager]

[image: Remove IIS 10 on Windows 2019 - Uncheck "Web Server (IIS)"]